# Logic App: Set "OptimizedForHighThroughput" in an ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

There's a Logic App feature to enable a workflow for high throughput (currently in preview).

Via the portal this can be enabled in the "Workflow settings" of your Logic App by enabling the "High throughput" switch under Runtime options.

Is there a way to set this option using ARM templates?
The Microsoft docs say:

> To configure high throughput mode, under the runtimeConfiguration of the workflow resource, set the operationOptions property to OptimizedForHighThroughput

So I tried adding runtimeConfiguration to my ARM template like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
  "name": "[variables('workflows_integra_send_name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Logic App - send"
  },
  "scale": null,
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "operationOptions ": "OptimizedForHighThroughput"
  },
  "properties": {...
```

But that leaves me with the following error message:

**The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'runtimeConfiguration' on object of type 'TemplateResource'. Path 'properties.template.resources[6].runtimeConfiguration', line 1, position 23494.'.**

Any help on where to configure this in my template is much appreciated!

Comment: try the latest api version

Comment: @4c74356b41 As far as I know '2017-07-01' is the latest schema/API version for Logic Apps.

Comment: there could be an api version. how do you know?

Comment: Because the current logic apps I deploy are on api version '2017-07-01' and the "Upgrade Schema" button (used to upgrade you Logic App to the latest schema) is greyed out.. so I assume it's on the latest version. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial and error I found out that the runtimeConfiguration had to go under the "properties" of the Logic App ARM template. Like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
  "name": "[variables('workflows_integra_send_name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Logic App - send"
  },
  "scale": null,
  "properties": {
    "state": "Enabled",
    "runtimeConfiguration": {
      "operationOptions": "OptimizedForHighThroughput"
    },...
```

Also there was a typo in my template (extra space behind operationOptions)